# Laravel authenticate via phone number

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I don't want to use Laravel's built in authentication because it has the traditional username/password approach. The way my system is authenticated is basically

1. You login with your Client ID and Last Name and they are tested against the database
2. Once they are correct, the user details (including phone number) are stored in a session variable and it sends you an OTP to your phone number. If the OTP matches, you are then taken to the home screen.

Being new, I just can't get my head around manually authenticating the user. In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users), it says to use `Auth::attempt()` but this compares the data against the database. The code I have is just comparing the random generated OTP.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't really know what to try that's why I'm stuck. But @ColqueCumber gave an answer so I'll try that. I apologize, I'm jumping from procedural PHP to Laravel so I'm very new to the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
Auth::login($user)
```

Will log the user in.